# How to know if an SDcard is about to fail?

Tags: windows-7, storage, sd-card

I have an SDcard that is still working fine for about 8 years now. I am using it for an DSLR camera. I am quite paranoid that it will soon stop working while taking photos of an important event. Are there ways to find out if it's about to fail?

Comment: When in doubt replace it with a new one.

Answer (score 2):

SD cards lack many of the lovely features more 'proper' storage has, so running things like smart tests is out of the question. Most tests involve writing to the card and reading back what was written to check for corruption. Depending on your OS something like H2testw might work.

"Its still working fine for about 8 years now" That's a long time for hardware- SD cards have gotten bigger and cheaper over time. You ought to replace it *pre-emptively*. Many of the failure modes of sd cards are *gradual* and you might not have the sudden catastrophic failure most people expect. There's a [photos.se](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/40489/what-causes-an-sd-card-to-go-corrupt) question that covers it in detail.

That said, many failure modes *are* sudden and catastrophic. *One is none* and you'd want spare SD cards if its really important. SO.. don't wait for failure. Plan for it.